# Replacing a string inside of multiple text files

Tags: windows, command-line, notepad++, sed

I am looking for a way to replace line 5 and line 7 in many documents inside of a directory. Line 5's offset and line 7's value are different for each of these documents, however, I need them to always be set to 0. This means line 5 should look like "color_stream_offset": 0," in all the documents and line 7 should look like "flags": 0," inside all of the documents.

I've attempted usage at SED, Notepad++ and none of them seem to be helpful. Each one of these documents has differences so I cannot just copy the file.

This is one of the many documents that needs replacing:

```
{
    "data": {
        "mesh": {
            "color_stream_count": 0,
            "color_stream_offset": 105920,
            "cull_distance": 1.0000000150474662e+30,
            "flags": 136,
            "lightmap_motifs": [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            ],
            "lightmap_names": [],
            "lightmap_offsets": [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            ],
            "mesh_name": "gomcbldf_00",
            "mesh_offset": 18172,
            "py/object": "lib.init_classes.Mesh",
            "tint": {
                "dimensions": 3,
                "py/object": "lib.ma_util.Vector",
                "x": 1.0,
                "y": 1.0,
                "z": 1.0
            }
        },
        "offset": 989012
    },
    "py/object": "lib.init_classes.ShapeData",
    "shape_type": "FWORLD_SHAPETYPE_MESH"
}
```

Comment: Please, don't give exqqmple as image, insert the text in te question instead. Also, add the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

I post following solution as a pragmatic one. To simplify it you can do it in two steps. You be warned - please make a **backup copy** of all files first.

I assume your files e.g `file-1.txt` and `file-2.txt`all have the extension *.txt and reside in folder e.g. **D:\_working**:

- First open **one** of the files in your working directory by Notepad++
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Go to the *Find in Files* tab
- Find what:`(.+)("color_stream_offset": )([0-9]{6}\,)`
- Replace with:`\1\20,`
- Filters: `*.txt`
- Directory: e.g. D:\_working
- Check `Match case`
- Search mode: `Regular expression`
- Click on <kbd>Replace in Files</kbd>
- Click on <kbd>OK</kbd> when you're really sure.

As a second step edit the Find What string to: `(.+)("flags": )([0-9]{3}\,)` and click on <kbd>Replace in Files</kbd>.

Please note the spaces in the Regex search string and change e.g. the digit `{6}` in the search string if you have different length here.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a single step:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:"color_stream_offset":|"flags":)\h*\K\d+`
- Replace with: `0`
- Filters: `Whatever you want`
- Directory: `Path\where\your\files\are`
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace in Files</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                           # non capture group
    "color_stream_offset":      # literally
  |                           # OR
    "flags":                    # literally
)                             # end group
\h*                 # 0 or more horizontal spaces
\K                  # forget all we've seen until this position
\d+                 # 1 or more digits
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]